# Gitignore files from an existing project

Tags: php, git, github, gitignore

I want to start a new repo on a current project I'm working on, the idea is to have a repo with, say 60% of the files in my project as a template so I can quickly clone it if I need to (I guess I could use gitignore to achieve that but maybe there is a better way of doing it).

For example: 
- Website 1 contains these files/folders:

```
    index.php
    app/
    config/
    css/
```

I want index.php and app/ to be in the repo as the code will be exactly the same for all future websites I clone. But I need config/ and css/ to be unique to each website.

So now if I go to Website 2 and clone the repo from website 1 I would get index.php and app/ but nothing else, which means I would have to copy all other files manually, Is the a better way to do this?

The reason being that when I upgrade files in the repo I can quickly pull/fetch them on the other clones without affecting the unique files, if that makes sense.

Maybe there's a simple way of doing this.

Comment: If you make a repository with the structure you want for new projects, you can clone it as the start of a new project (and pull in "common" updates in the future). That said you're better off rethinking along the lines of separate repos, dependencies and not having a single frankenstein repo. A gitignore file has nothing to do with this.

Comment: How do I pull in "common" updates?

Comment: By having multiple remotes e.g. `git pull template/master`. see how composer sets up clones for example.

Answer (score 0):

Yea,

Copy what you want your new template repo to contain into a new folder structure and then create the new repo from that.

Answer (score -1):

If the files are ignored, then you cannot get git to pull them.
If you are really desperate, you could make a new branch, where you remove the gitignore file (or the corresponding rows), then commit all files and pull them from the other server.

After that, you reverse your commit on webserver 1, or you unfollow css, config files.
On webserver 2 you would need to manually unfollow the css, config files too after the pull.

I would rather copy the files manually.

Comment: `If the files are ignored, then you cannot get git to pull them` not true, -1.